# Does anyone have a backup of the Silicon Image SiI3531 Management Utility for Windows?

Tags: sata

This controller was originally made by Silicon Image but the company assets are now owned by Lattice Semiconductor. There used to be a links to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of this software but the website is offline and they were not archived by the Wayback Machine.

Lattice Semiconductor provides a [legacy archive](https://www.latticesemi.com/Support/ASSPSoftwareArchive) of some of these files but many are missing. For example, the Management Utility for the SiI3531 controller is available for 64-but only and is an older version 1.5.12.0.

I am looking for the following versions:

```
1.5.20.0
1.5.18.8
1.5.13.3
```

Here is the support page archived on the Wayback Machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20101230083613/http://www.siliconimage.com/support/searchresults.aspx?pid=80&cat=11

The dead links with file names are:

```
http://www.siliconimage.com/docs/SiI3531-W-R-1.5.20.zip
http://www.siliconimage.com/docs/SiI3531-W-R_15188.msi
http://www.siliconimage.com/docs/3531-W-I32-R_15133.msi
```

Comment: You can try [this link](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=51597). I'm not making an account to see what's behind the sign in.

Comment: That's a link to the older version 1.5.12.0 as I mentioned in my question.